# missing dependencies in latest spring security test

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-test

I need to resolve certain methods (status, jsonPath, content) mentioned in code shown below -

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/token")
            .with(getAuthentication(getOauthTestAuthentication()))
            .sessionAttr("scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext", getOauth2ClientContext()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username").value("cominventor"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.token").value("my-fun-token"));
```

When I searched for related projects containing these methods, many of them are importing the following

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
```

The problem is that I am unable to find a counterpart in package spring-security-test with version 4.2.2.RELEASE

The closest options that could have worked but haven't are

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher.*;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

The above don't contain the methods I am looking for. Any idea where should I look for these methods or their newer counterparts.

Comment: They seem to have replaced methods with elaborate classes to achieve the same functionality. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything worked out once I set the spring-security-test version to 4.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: good catch; but aside downgrading the version of spring-security-test, isn't there any other option??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it importing the artifact

```
org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:4.2.3.RELEASE
```

I am using `spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.3`, and for some reason the folks at Spring decided not to include `spring-security-test` in its POM.